# Android import CSV to SQLite not first row

Tags: java, android, sqlite, csv, import

I want to import into SQLite database table, the data in a CSV file, but the first line of the CSV file contains information that I do not want to import. How can I do? this is the method I use to import the file:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File exportDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());
 File csvFile = new File(exportDir, getString(R.string.app_name)+".csv");

 try {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
String[] vv = null;
  while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
   cv.clear();
   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat currFormater  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
      String eDDte;
try
`{
Date nDate = currFormater.parse(vv[0]);
            eDDte = postFormater.format(nDate);
            cv.put(EntrateUsciteTable.DATA,eDDte);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
        }

SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 db.insert(EntrateUsciteTable.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
}
dataRead.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("TAG",e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example with a counter:

```
int counter = 0;
while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
    if(counter == 0) {
        continue;
        counter++;
    } else {
       // Do the insert
    }
}
```